# Does one cup of coffee pollute as much as a 10km car drive?

Tags: pollution, coffee

I've heard such a statement made off-hand, and don't have any source for it, or any precision on type of coffee, preparation, what type of pollution is taken into account, etc.

I'd like to know if there is any truth to it, but google mostly gives me low-on-content pages.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Skeptics.SE! I'm afraid that if you can't provide a source for the claim, then this question will most likely be closed as off-topic.

Comment: Too bad. Thanks for the heads-up!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If by "pollution" you mean carbon dioxide release:

**The Eco Guide** discusses the amount of CO<sub>2</sub> generated by coffee from growth through shipping to processing and the machines in the cafe where you drink it.

In [Examining the Carbon Footprint of Coffee](https://theecoguide.org/examining-carbon-footprint-coffee) it says

> This comes out to approximately .275, or about a quarter a pound of CO<sub>2</sub> is produced for every cup we drink.

This is 125 gm per cup.

---

The **UK Goverment** website gives the average CO<sub>2</sub> emissions for new cars in 2015.

In [New car carbon dioxide emissions](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/new-car-carbon-dioxide-emissions) it says

> The average carbon dioxide emissions of cars registered for the first time in the second quarter of 2015 (April to June) was 122.1 grams of carbon dioxide per kilometre.

This is 1221 gm per 10 km.

---

The amount from the 10 km drive is **ten times** greater than from the coffee, yet

- the assessment for coffee included every accountable source of CO<sub>2</sub> from bean to cup
- the assessment for a car journey is only the actual fuel burnt, not its extraction, refinement and distribution, and not the manufacturing emissions of the car itself

Even without those overheads, the car is far more polluting.
So based on that, the answer is **no**.

Comment: Would be interesting to compare PAH and other pollutants. Plus 1

Comment: @Alchimista aren't they produced by inefficient combustion? If so, *some* might be emitted by producing coffee, but wouldn't considering them make the claim even less true?

Comment: I don't think coffe pollutes more (note that all activities to make the car and that move it shall be considered, too) but roasting coffee produces quite a lot of stuff. It is more a curiosity, anyway.